# Can the Office 365 license be used in a different country?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I have Office 365 Home Premium, bought in India, but now shifted to the U.S.A. I can't use this license here because I have a problem installing it. Can the Office 365 license be used in a different country?

Comment: Office 365 accounts are not region specific.  What problems do you have exactly?